# Why my texture is not the same in blender and when i export collada?

Tags: uv, texture-baking, collada

I don't know why, i try everything after a bake to put my texture instead of the old one. The only way i see my old texture is in the outliner but i don't know why it's there because in my shader the only texture i have is the baked one...
[image]

I'm trying to get a baked texture to export in collada for playing with webgl after but this is really hard to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you're using cycles. Save the texture you baked to a file and use it as a texture in a Blender Internal material, and the export should work. I export from BI to Collada for use in web and game engines all the time and it works nicely.

Related to this question: [Why does the collada exporter not export texture references?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3778/why-does-the-collada-exporter-not-export-texture-references)

Comment: thank you it works now.
That's sad that we have to use BI for using the cycles baking in collada, all i do is a simple diffuse material, not very complex :(