# How to export materials to collada file correctly?

Tags: texturing, materials, collada

I am now using Blender 2.8 and create my own model, I add a new material and
link an image texture node to its color channel. However, when I try to export it to a collada file, and reimport it, the image texture disappear! It works only if I use Principled BSDF shader, it fails when I use other shader types such as Emission shader.
[image: Principled BSDF shader]

[image: reimport case1]
the selected object is the reimport mesh, the image texture is preserved in this case.

[image: Emission shader]
[image: reimport case2]
again, the selected object is the reimport mesh, the image texture is missing in this case.

So what is the proper way to export materials to collada file, or is it possible to export image textures correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks! Your explanation helps a lot !

Comment: @DavidWillo Hi, as I have the same problem with Blender v3.6.4 can you tell me in which way the link provided help you? Cos I could not take nothing from it that would help yet constantly seeing him giving that exact link for any kind of problem related to this stuff (dae not exporting images, although the texture option COPY is checked). I am really trying here to understand how, in what way or form the info there helped you so that I can use it for my problem of the same kind now in year 2023.

Answer (score 0):

Only Principled BSDF will work with collada export
Check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243157/135402

Comment: Sorry, but regardless of the node it still does not export textures when exporting to Collada (.dae) in Blender v3.6.4, yet dae has absolutely no problem with textures as other apps export to it with no problem incl. texture refferences for the materials.